# Get a part of document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Suppose i have following document in some collection

```
{
        "name": "Man1",            
        "Childrens": [
             {
                 "name": "Children 1",
                 "age": "12"
             },
             {
                 "name": "Children 2",
                 "age": "18"
             },
         ]
    }
```

how to get output of the query as i.e.get child where age of the child is 18

```
{
      "name": "Children 2",
      "age": "18"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to find the document and [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) for projection of the data

```
db.collection.find({
  Childrens: {
    $elemMatch: {
      age: "18"
    }
  }
},
{
  Childrens: {
    $elemMatch: {
      age: "18"
    }
  },
  _id: 0
})
```

OutPut --> [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iuvo_EqWKFG)

```
[
  {
    "Childrens": [
      {
        "age": "18",
        "name": "Children 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: i will test this, but before this can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977712/how-to-get-a-document-in-cosmosdb-via-a-nested-property-through-net-mongodb-dri

Comment: I don't know how to do that with `.net mongo-driver`... Otherwise I would have answered yet

Comment: @AnkitRaonka What about this answer?