# How to get a document in mongoDb via a nested property through .net mongoDb driver

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose i have following document in some collection

```
   [{
            "name": "Man1",            
            "Childrens": [
                 {
                     "name": "Children 1",
                     "age": "12"
                 },
                 {
                     "name": "Children 2",
                     "age": "18"
                 },
             ]
        },
{
            "name": "Man1",            
            "Childrens": [
                 {
                     "name": "Children 3",
                     "age": "12"
                 },
                 {
                     "name": "Children 4",
                     "age": "18"
                 },
             ]
        }
]
```

i want to get the document where name of one of the children is "Children 1"

I want to achieve this via .net mongo driver

```
var bQuery = String.Format("{{ '{0}':'{1}' }}","Childrens.name","Children 1");
var filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(bQuery);
result = await db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName).Find<T>(filter).ToListAsync();
```

but this return empty list
where as if i do

```
var bQuery = String.Format("{{ '{0}':'{1}' }}","name","Man1");
```

it works

so i am not able to make it work when we search via nested property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use below code and i have tested successfully:

```
{ "Childrens": { $elemMatch: { "name": "Children 1"} } }
```

And your code would be:

```
var filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("{ \"Childrens\": { $elemMatch: { \"name\": \"Children 1\"} } }");
result = await db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName).Find<T>(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: what if i dont want the full document, only the object of the child?

Comment: Per my knowledge, i don't know how to do that, you can post this as a question to another thread.